# How can I fetch a satellite image of the MapKit location as Apple Map app does?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

In my application I have an MapView with autocomplete. When user selects some place I show a pin on the map view with `details` button. Then I want to show a static satellite image of the place the same as Apple's map application does it.

Are there some ways I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a static image of the selected place on the `MapView`, you can use [MKMapSnaphotter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapSnapshotter_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKMapSnapshotter) class for this purpose with satellite map type. When you click on the details button, pass [MKSnapshotOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapSnapshotOptions_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapSnapshotOptions/region) to your detail view controller like this:

```
MKMapSnapshotOptions *options = [MKMapSnapshotOptions new];
options.region = mapView.region;
options.size =  mapView.frame.size;
options.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
options.showsBuildings = YES;
options.scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
detailViewController.options = options;
```

And then in your detail view controller create a snapshot image and show it like this:

```
 MKMapSnapshotter *snapshotter = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc] initWithOptions:self.options];
[snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot,    NSError *error) {
    if (error) return; //And show error message;
    imageView.image = snapshot.image;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

`MKMapView` has a property `mapType`. Set this property to `MKMapType.Satellite`.

Possible types are:

- Standard
- Satellite
- Hybrid

See [mapType in MKMapView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/mapType)